# Add a Scrollbar to a Modal Window

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, scrollbar, frontend

Hello Fellow Developers,

I'm trying to get the modal window to have a scrollbar (screenshot below).  The content is set to overflow-y: scroll and I've used the following method:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

...but only the main body div is picked up.  I've tried adding this css to the modal with the overflow and it still doesn't work.  Anyone see something I don't?

[BETA PAGE](https://gettv.situationdev.net/)

[image: screenshot]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There was pseudo element that was inherited to display: none.

For future devs:

1) Inspect the element in question
2) In the styles tab, scroll down to the bottom and you'll find the modal's Pseudo ::scrollbar element styles.  If this is blank, then you have another issue.